# How to cancel sending "wait to send" email in Outlook for Mac

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

Outlook for Mac (16.62) now includes a "wait to send" feature, allowing you to specify a delay before sent messages are actually sent to the server. The idea being that if you realise you've made a mistake a few seconds after sending, you can cancel and amend the email. I've set a delay of 15 seconds.

That's great, my emails are indeed delayed by 15 seconds. However, this is only a useful feature if there is actually a way of cancelling the email during the delay period. I would expect the email to temporarily appear in an 'Outbox' folder, or perhaps in 'Sent' with some indication that it is about to send. However, this isn't the case – as far as I can tell, my emails just disappear completely for the 15 seconds. The only way I can see to cancel sending is to disable my WiFi during the 15-second period.

Am I missing something? Is there some way to cancel sending *within Outlook*, rather than taking the somewhat more drastic route of disabling my WiFi router?

**Edit**: As this is a new feature in Outlook, it seems there is some confusion with the existing "Send Later" feature. "Wait to send" is also known as "Undo Send" and is set via **Preferences > Composing**. It looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Can you check if the emails appear in `Drafts` ?

Comment: I'm only aware of the long existing *'Delay Delivery'* function, which parks it in the outbox on your device rather than somewhere server side. I also can't find anything specific that describes the behaviour above. Is *"wait to send"* the exact term used in your English language mail client, or is the term translated to English from another language? And can you maybe include a screenshot of said setting in your client so we have a starting point?

Comment: Yes, they are in Drafts. I should have looked a little harder! @MiG, this is a new feature sometimes known as "Undo Send". I've added info to the question above, but have now found the answer as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it, thanks to User552853. The unsent emails don't appear in Outbox or Sent; they are in **Drafts**.

Comment: You should probably let @User552853 write that answer and accept it :)

Comment: Glad your issue has been solved. And i've put the solution together as answer, would you mind marking the helpful post as an answer? Which would benefit others who also has similar issues in forum.

Answer (score -2):

**Summary:**

The unsent emails don't appear in Outbox or Sent; they are in Drafts.